# Filtering in python with two columns and selecting in each column the applicable fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter a dataframe on column A and column D with Column A and column D being the key filters.
The dataframes name is df.

```
A               B             C         D           E
Peter           Sydney        Perth    Pan         Fairy
Peter           Adelaide      NSW      Meat        Garden
Peter           NSW           Perth    Pan         Gnome
```

Column A = Peter and Column D = Pan
I wrote the code below and am getting an error. Please assist

```
df_new = df[df['A'] == "Peter"] and [df['C'] == "Pan"]
```

Comment: `mask = (df['A'] == "Peter") & (df['C'] == "Pan"); df[mask]`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
DF2 = df[(df['A']=='Peter') & (df['D']== 'Pan') ]
```

output

```
       A       B      C    D      E
0  Peter  Sydney  Perth  Pan  Fairy
2  Peter     NSW  Perth  Pan  Gnome
```

in your code, you got the paranthesis wrong.